# Text shown outside inline-block DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` tag with `inline-block` set for css display in order to fit size to its content. However, I noticed that in FireFox, some letters being that last are shown partially outside the `<div>` tag, such as the letter "f". Any clue how to fix this without changing padding?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 200px;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 0px solid red;
                outline: 0px dotted blue;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
                max-width: 1000px;
                max-height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body">
                <div id="div" contenteditable="true">fff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an example, on jsfiddle.net or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your `<div>` tag with `inline-block` a border of some px, like `border: solid 8px yellow;`. You need not give a complete border, instead a `border-right` is enough for your problem. But I applied a 4 side border in my fiddle.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/2PU8u/1/)*** is a Live Demo.

Comment: He has mentioned not to use padding

Comment: I want the DIV to resize correctly not by adding extra stuff like padding, borders and outlines

Answer (score 0):

Either your div tag has some inherited styles or another element close by is overlapping with it. Try looking at the page with another browser and also view the div tag element using your browser's web inspector to see what extra styles are being cascaded into the element (if any). It could also be a user-agent CSS problem (when a browser has default CSS settings that interfere with what you expect to appear on the page).